# Entering in if block when it wasn't supposed to after project conversion

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6

A few days ago we converted a vb6 project to be a .net one.

After some testing, a weird behavior showed up.

```
If conditiona a <> 1 And conditionB = 1 And conditionC <> 0 Then

<block>

EndIf
```

The block is being executed even if it's false. It works when i change And for AndAlso. Why is this happening? It works fine on VB6.

Comment: Are your conditions really a test between an integer and a constant or are in reality calls to methods that return an integer?

Comment: What are the values of `conditionaa`, `conditionB` and `conditionC`?

Comment: I mistook conditiona. It was suposed to be conditiona = 21. But even so, when i check it on immediate window, its value returns is a decimal (1D). ConditionB had dbnull.value as its value. And conditionc had 5 as its value. The only condition evaluated correctly, was the last one.

Comment: How can DBNull.Value ever be a 1?

Comment: Dunno. That's why i came here to ask what is going on.

Comment: Turn option strict on.

Comment: But some errors showed up: strict on disables late binding. Or something like that.

Comment: @JoaoVictor Please confirm the you can run this code without error: `MsgBox((CObj(DBNull.Value) = 1).ToString)`

Comment: "Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'"

Comment: The we can conclude that the `ConditionB` is NOT a `DBNull.Value` don't you agree?

Comment: I agree. But no exceptions are being thrown, no errors, nothing. And false And False and True, should be false, am i wrong? So why the if block is still being executed?

Comment: @JoaoVictor I agree, but since no error is thrown and the conditions are met, the returned value is not a DBNull.Value, in fact I it must b a `1`.

Comment: @JoaoVictor Test my answer and you will see that this will throw an error, thus `conditionB` can never be a DBNull.Value. Then what is it? Well, since the conditions are met, it must be a `1`.

Answer (score 1):

By reproducing your code with your values, this will throw an `Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'.` error.

```
Private Sub Test()
    If conditionA() <> 21 And conditionB() = 1 And conditionC() <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Ops")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function conditionA() As Object
    Return 1D
End Function

Private Function conditionB() As Object
    Return DBNull.Value
End Function

Private Function conditionC() As Object
    Return 5I
End Function
```

So I think it's fair to assume that the reason why the block is executed is simply because the conditions are met.

When dealing with unknown types this is how you should compare the objects:

```
If ((Not Object.Equals(conditionA(), 21I)) And Object.Equals(conditionB(), 1I) And (Not Object.Equals(conditionC(), 0I))) Then
    '<block>
End If
```